# What is Scala type and @field used for?

Tags: scala, annotations

I'm new to Scala and I got Scala code written below

```
import cucumber.deps.com.thoughtworks.xstream.annotations.XStreamConverter

object Transformer {
    type Converter = XStreamConverter @field
}
```

My question is, does typing `@Converter` means

```
@XStreamConverter
@field
class AAA {
}
```

Secondly, what does `@field` for? What would happen when `@field` or its alias is placed at class level?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`@field` is a [meta-annotation](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.annotation.meta.package). The type alias `Converter`:

```
type Converter = XStreamConverter @field
```

It is a more readable version of something like:

```
@(XStreamConverter @field)()
```

> field
>
> Applied to the definition of an annotation to specify its
>   default target, a field in this case.

Comment: what happen if that `@field` is used at class level?

Answer (score -3):

Converter is just another name (alias) for XStreamConverter, another example

type Name = String

@field looks like some sort of annotation as in Java.